# How to add in a sql query a condition that checks if ckeckboxe are checked?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have several comboboxes and I would like to check those that are checked to retrieve their values ​​and use them in a sql query.

I tried to put all the checkboxes in a flowLayoutPanel and use a foreach to retrieve their contents.I think it's a syntax problem in my sql query.

```cs
 List<string> selection = new List<string>();
            foreach (CheckBox cb in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                if (cb.Checked)
                    selection.Add(cb.Text);
            }

 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT JOB_HEADER.P FROM JOB_HEADER WHERE JOB_HEADER.MODE_F = selection")
```

Here is the mistake I get : 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid column name 'selection'.

Sorry if the solution is obvious I am a beginner. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How does the `MODE_F` column look like, what are its possible values? What re you checkboxes' values? Also, which database are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)?

Comment: You are going to have to iterate through the list (selection) and build the sql statement from those values by using OR to select JOB_HEADER.MODE_F = this OR JOB_HEADER.MODE_F = that. Etc...

Comment: The best way of finding error is top use SQL Server Management Studio and put query into a new Query Windows in SSMS.  The error message ii SSMS are 1000 times better than c# and you will quickly find reason for issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual error is caused by the word *selection*. This is not the list variable but a literal text inside a string and the database engine has no way to know how to extract the list values from that word. So it thinks that you have written a column name and it cannot find it.

The solution is more complex than you think.

You need a collection of parameters and a collection of names to put inside an IN clause

```
int pcount = 1;

// This is where we keep the placeholder text for the parameters 
List<string> names = new List<string>();

// This is the list of parameters built using the checkboxes checked state
List<SqlParameter> prms = new List<SqlParameter>();

foreach (CheckBox cb in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        names.Add("@p" + pcount);
        prms.Add(new SqlParameter 
        {
            ParameterName = "@p" + pcount, 
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, 
            Value = cb.Text,
            // For performance it would be useful also to specify the column size
            // Size = 100,
        });
        pcount++;
    }
}

// Build the sql command adding all the parameters placeholders inside an IN clause
string cmdText = @"SELECT JOB_HEADER.P FROM JOB_HEADER WHERE JOB_HEADER.MODE_F IN(";
cmdText += string.Join(",", names) + ")";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
// Give the parameters collection to the command
command.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray());
```

Comment: Actually it seems much more complex than I had imagined.
Your solution seems perfect, but I have two errors in my code.
One on 'SqlDbType.NVarChar' return ithis : Invalid initializer member declarator.
And on 'command.Parameters.AddRange(prms.ToArray);' return : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'SqlParameter[]'
I will try to find the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: I see, please refresh the page. I think I have fixed the problems noted

Answer (score 0):

you should add List of items to a string:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("//connectionstring");         

var inList = "(" + string.Join(", ", selection.Select(t => "@" + t)) + ")";         

string query = String.Format("SELECT JOB_HEADER.P FROM JOB_HEADER WHERE JOB_HEADER.MODE_F  IN ({0})", inList);         

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
```

Or use add parameter:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2][1]

Answer (score -1):

Your error is coming from the term 'selection' in your SQL statement.  You're attempting to pass the name of your List<>, instead of the Values of the checked checkboxes in that List<>

Original:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT JOB_HEADER.P FROM JOB_HEADER WHERE JOB_HEADER.MODE_F = selection");
```

Try this instead (I haven't tested this, but it should be close):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT JOB_HEADER.P FROM JOB_HEADER WHERE JOB_HEADER.MODE_F IN(" + string.Format("'{0}'", string.Join("','", selection.Select(i => i.Replace("'", "''")))) + ")");
```

[Edited suggestion to assume strings, and not integers]

Comment: I didn't downvote but it's probably because the string in the join are not wrapped with the apostrophe to denote text.

Comment: We don't know that strings are being passed, though.  That's why I declared the assumption about it being integers.

Comment: Well, the op is demonstrating in their code that they are storing cb.Text into a List<string> so there's that.

Comment: That's fair.  I've edited my answer to assume strings instead of integers.

Comment: Well, again, I didn't downvote but I still think you might as well remove this as an assumption still isn't a good method, look at what Steve showed. Using parameters removes this issue altogether making one piece of code work for all types (int, string, datetimes, etc...)

Comment: @CharlesMay well, in all fairness, Me too I also have assumed a string collection because I build a collection of NVarChar parameters. I assume that the downvote is related to the habit of string concatenation instead, albeit here the sql is built from the checkbox text and that should not be easily manipulable to build an Sql Injection attack

Comment: That's true @steve, I didn't catch that. Anyway, just didn't want to see him keep getting downvoted for what I `Thought` was the reason it happened in the first place. P.S. your code is missing a semicolon ;)

Comment: @CharlesMay falcon eyes here! :-) Don't appreciate a sophisticated IDE enough until you try to write code without its help.

Comment: I kept it simple and similar to what the OP originally posted, since he/she stated that they were a beginner.  It's sometimes a balancing act, trying to give a beginner a valid answer, without providing something that they may not even understand.  To truly handle the SQL calls correctly, you wouldn't have any hard-coded SQL, and would instead use procs with params.  And technically, surrounding each value in the IN( ) list with quotes will also work for passing ints, strings, datetimes, etc.  Technically, my answer is also correct, and functional.

Comment: @DBro, I totally agree. Your code (other than not having apostrophes) works. And it could have just been someone that didn't even understand what your statement did in the first place.

Comment: @steve, it appears that if you remove the type, it will set its own type from the value. I don't know if this is a good thing or not but I copied your code over and removed the type and set value to  pcount and it showed the type as an Int in the debugger dropdown. Would this have the same problems as .AddWithValue does?